# hibernate mapping throw exception

Tags: hibernate

I don't know why I can't build it?? They throw this exception: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: product is not mapped [from product]

My Sample Code:

```
public Product[] searchProductByCatalog(String catalogid, String keyword) {
    String sql = "from product where 1";

        if (keyword.trim().equals("") == false) {
            sql += " and product_name like '%" + keyword + "%'";
        }
        if (catalogid.trim().equals("-1") == false) {
            sql += " and catalog_id = " + Integer.parseInt(catalogid);
        }
    try {

        session.getTransaction().begin();
        Query query = session.createQuery(sql);
        List listProduct = query.list();
        Product[] product = new Product[listProduct.size()];
        listProduct.toArray(product);
        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return product;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (session.getTransaction().isActive()) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

And this is my mapping:
Product Mapping:

```
<class name="pojo.Product" table="product" catalog="shoesshopdb">
    <id name="idProduct" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id_product" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="catalog" class="pojo.Catalog" fetch="select" lazy="true">
        <column name="catalog_id" />
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="productName" type="string">
        <column name="product_name" length="45" />
    </property>
    <property name="date" type="date">
        <column name="date" length="10" />
    </property>
    <property name="author" type="string">
        <column name="author" length="45" />
    </property>
    <property name="price" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="price" />
    </property>
    <property name="linkimage" type="string">
        <column name="linkimage" length="45" />
    </property>
</class>
```

Catalog Mapping:

```
<class name="pojo.Catalog" table="catalog" catalog="shoesshopdb">
    <id name="idCatalog" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="ID_CATALOG" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="catalogName" type="string">
        <column name="Catalog_Name" length="45" />
    </property>
    <set name="products" inverse="true">
        <key>
            <column name="catalog_id" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="pojo.Product" />
    </set>
</class>
```

Comment: can you share your exception ?

Comment: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: product is not mapped [from product]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class name is `Product`, not `product`. Case matters.

Comment: sorry... when I run this method searchProductByCatalog("1", "");
They throw exception org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: 1 near line 1, column 25 [from pojo.Product where 1 and catalog_id = 1]

Comment: What you're using in your code is an HQL query. Not an SQL query as you named it. And HQL uses entities, properties and associations. Never table names and column names. product_name should be productName. catalog_id should be catalog.id. Read the documentation on HQL. It seems you don't even know it exists and is different from SQL. Moreover, `where 1` is incorrect (in HQL as in SQL).